# Not unique table/alias on join

Tags: mysql, join

I intend to do an update based on join, but getting an error. What is missing?

```
update
     vna.patients,
     vna.patient_observations,
     vna.studies,
     vna.series,
     vna.instances,
     vna.sop_classes,
     vna.files,
     vna.modalities,
     vna.issuers
join patient_observations on atients.patient_id=patient_observations.patient_id 
join studies
  on  patient_observations.study_id=studies.study_id
  AND studies.patient_id=patients.patient_id
join series
  on series.study_id=studies.study_id
join instances
  on instances.series_id=series.series_id
join sop_classes
  on sop_classes.sop_class_id=instances.sop_class_id
join files
  on files.instance_id=instances.instance_id
left join modalities
  on modalities.modality_id=series.modality_id
left join issuers
  on (patients.issuer_of_patient_identifier=issuers.issuer_id)
set PATIENT_NAME='AAPM'
WHERE PATIENT_IDENTIFIER='TG18-2002';

ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'patient_observations'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify table names again which appears in join part

```
UPDATE 
  vna.patients 
  JOIN patient_observations 
    ON patients.patient_id = patient_observations.patient_id 
  JOIN studies 
    ON patient_observations.study_id = studies.study_id 
    AND studies.patient_id = patients.patient_id 
  JOIN series 
    ON series.study_id = studies.study_id 
  JOIN instances 
    ON instances.series_id = series.series_id 
  JOIN sop_classes 
    ON sop_classes.sop_class_id = instances.sop_class_id 
  JOIN files 
    ON files.instance_id = instances.instance_id 
  LEFT JOIN modalities 
    ON modalities.modality_id = series.modality_id 
  LEFT JOIN issuers 
    ON (patients.issuer_of_patient_identifier = issuers.issuer_id)
  SET PATIENT_NAME = 'AAPM' 
WHERE PATIENT_IDENTIFIER = 'TG18-2002' ;
```

Comment: @kingsmasher1 but i suggest you to have a look at the 2nd approach propose by Gordon Linoff may be its simple update and don't need all the joins

Comment: Joins are needed as each of the table has foreign key references to other and there can be updates in multiple tables simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you mixing the two different `JOIN` syntaxes?  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause (and that goes for `UPDATE` as well).  I think you intend:

```
update vna.patients p
       patient_observations po
       on p.patient_id = po.patient_id join
       studies st
       on po.study_id = st.study_id AND
          st.patient_id = p.patient_id join
       series s
       on s.study_id = st.study_id join
       instances i
       on i.series_id = s.series_id join
       sop_classes sc
       on sc.sop_class_id = i.sop_class_id join
       files f
       on f.instance_id = i.instance_id left join
       modalities m
       on m.modality_id = s.modality_id  left join
       issuers iss
       on (p.issuer_of_patient_identifier = iss.issuer_id)
    set p.PATIENT_NAME = 'AAPM'
    where p.PATIENT_IDENTIFIER = 'TG18-2002';
```

That seems way too complicated.  I'm guessing you just want:

```
update vna.patients p
    set p.PATIENT_NAME = 'AAPM'
    where p.PATIENT_IDENTIFIER = 'TG18-2002';
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear, the table `patient_observations` is listed twice in the table references in your query. Give the second one a different alias if you really need to join it again in the same query:

```
...
vna.issuers 
join patient_observations as po2 on patients. ....
```

Otherwise, remove one of them.

Also try to use the ANSI SQL join syntax instead of this old syntax.